# Help troubleshoot netowrking fail? Can't connect via wifi or ethernet, ping localhost works, but not pinging any other address

Tags: networking

I'm running Peppermint 7 on an old EeePC 4G netbook. Everything was working fine until I noticed a few days ago that it couldn't connect to the internet, even when plugged into my router via ethernet cable. If I try to ping 8.8.8.8 I'm told network isn't available, but pinging localhost works just fine. Network-manager is running, I tried first nmcli (I usually run CLI) and then network-manager in the gui, but didn't see anything obviously wrong. When running an X server it seems to be trying over and over again to connect. I tried various fixes from people having connectivity issues but it's such a broad problem that none of them seem to apply/work.

Here's the output for ifconfig:

```
enp3s0    Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:1e:8c:cf:58:33  
          UP BROADCAST MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:167 errors:0 dropped:4 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:157 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:3
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:63028 (63.0 KB)  TX bytes:22706 (22.7 KB)
          Memory:fbfc0000-fc000000 

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback  
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1
          RX packets:3086 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:3086 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1 
          RX bytes:247336 (247.3 KB)  TX bytes:247336 (247.3 KB)

wlp1s0    Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:15:af:7f:a5:fa  
          inet6 addr: fe80::ff9a:f438:43f3:c80c/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:441 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:666 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:191066 (191.0 KB)  TX bytes:109498 (109.4 KB)
```

What else is needed to diagnose the issue? Thank you!

Comment: `localhost` exists only inside the computer ... sounds like you have no network connectivity at all ... pinging the gateway would verify local LAN connectivity ... gateway is the router

Comment: Welcome to the site. What happens if you try: `sudo dhclient enp3s0`? or `sudo dhclient wlp1s0`?

Comment: @user1794469 - in both cases I get the same error: "Inconsistency detected by ld.so: ../sysdeps/i386/dl-machine.h: 614: elf_machine_rel_relative: Assertion `ELF32_R_TYPE (reloc->r_info) == R_386_RELATIVE' failed!"

For the record, ethernet was disconnected when trying this, but I doubt it makes a difference.

Comment: This seems to imply that you have a bigger problem than just a misconfiguration of networking. Poking around a little others indicate that this is maybe a memory problem or corrupt package. Solutions seem to be to reinstall the broken packages, maybe someone else can help you figure out which need to be reinstalled.